# how to find the length of nested json array in javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

see this is my json response from server

```
{ "status": {    "statusCode": 200,"title": " needs", "classname": "NeedController" }, "needs": { "Needs": [{needTitle": "Need a book","needDescription": "story book","fromCustomer": "abc","needDate": "2014-05-15T12:57:13Z","needID": 23, "referrals":{"referrals":[{"referredBy":"xyz","referredOn":"2013-11-19T06:56:18Z","rererralId":3,"referralStatus":"declined","needId":3}]}}
```

i want to calculate the length of this referral array.
`"referrals":{"referrals":[{"referredBy":"xyz","referredOn":"2013-11-19T06:56:18Z","rererralId":3,"referralStatus":"declined","needId":3}]}`
this is my javascript code
function successCallback(responseObj){

```
alert(JSON.stringify(responseObj));//above response 
var dataj=(JSON.stringify(responseObj));
```

$.each(responseObj.needs.Needs,function(i){
alert(responseObj.needs.Needs.referrals.referrals.length);//this is not giving me length.

});
}

Comment: why do u have a referrals key inside referrals key???

Comment: @rajesh..sorry thats response from server..i cant change anything .just i need is to calculate the length of referral array.

Answer (score 0):

var JSON = { "status": { "statusCode": 200,"title": " needs", "classname": "NeedController" }, "needs": { "Needs": [{"needTitle": "Need a book","needDescription": "story book","fromCustomer": "abc","needDate": "2014-05-15T12:57:13Z","needID": 23, "referrals":{"referrals":[{"referredBy":"xyz","referredOn":"2013-11-19T06:56:18Z‌​","rererralId":3,"referralStatus":"declined","needId":3}]}}]}};

alert(JSON.needs.Needs[0].referrals.referrals.length);

As per the above JSON, this is how you find the length.

Comment: no..its not malformed..i have edited my que.but see this is whole json response{ "status": {    "statusCode": 200,"title": " needs", "classname": "NeedController" }, "needs": { "Needs": [{needTitle": "Need a book","needDescription": "story book","fromCustomer": "abc","needDate": "2014-05-15T12:57:13Z","needID": 23, "referrals":{"referrals":[{"referredBy":"xyz","referredOn":"2013-11-19T06:56:18Z","rererralId":3,"referralStatus":"declined","needId":3}]}}and from this response i want to calculate length of  the nested  array referrals

Answer (score -1):

Assuming **data** is the response variable, you can get the length of the referrals array using

```
data["needs"]["referrals"]["referrals"].length
```